# (missing .modinfo section or name field): No module found in object

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to run a kernel module , however I got invalid module format when I try to load it using insmod
`insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mymodule.ko: Invalid module format`

running `dmesg` I got the following output
`(missing .modinfo section or name field): No module found in object [] module: x86/modules: Skipping invalid relocation target, existing value is nonzero for type 1, loc 00000`

Makefile

```
obj-m = mymodule.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

mymodule.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>



MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("ME");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("TEST of The bla bla bla");


static int __init ModuleInit(void) {
    /*
     Some Code
    */
    return 0;

}

static void __exit ModuleExit(void) {
        printk ("Module EXIT");
}

module_init(ModuleInit);
module_exit(ModuleExit);
```

kernel version :  5.13.0-30-generic

Comment: What does modinfo mymodule.ko say? Fix it.

Comment: RUn `file mymodule.ko`. Also, you missed `\n` at the end of string literal.